# How to split data from MongoDB for each individual worker?

Tags: mongodb

I have DB server (MongoDB) with rows that should be processed down to workers. Each worker lives on own server in cluster. Is it possible somehow to split data from Mongo in automatic way for each worker in cluster so that rows will not overlap?

Ideally I want to make it work like this:

1. DB Server creates N subsets of data, where N = count of workers (obviosly I can add and remove workers and N should update => db subsets should reorganize).
2. Worker pulls data that is appropriate only for him and processes it.

I imagine it as something like replication, but for workers.

Comment: If I understad it well, you want to divided your documents into "buckets" of the same size ? Do you have any field suitable for that purpose ? I think about something like `_id % N`...

Comment: I think it is called sharding. From what I've googled - by range seems best option for me, since it is possible easily add new workers and remove them. Is is right solution?

Comment: _sharding_ is used to balance data among several MongoDB servers. From your description, it is not clear to me if you have a 1-to-1 mapping (or even identity) between those MongoDB instances and your "workers".

Comment: Ideally, none of worker should know about the MongoDB instance. It just wants to do something like model.pull({filter_here: 'blah-blah'}) and query should work only for subset that none of other workers will hit at any point.